# Stateful APi Auth and web auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

so i have a web app that uses sanctum for api authentication and also has an admin dashboard on the same app. After setting up my sanctum auth my normal web auth does not work anymore.

Here is my login page code for my admin auth;

```
        if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $this->email, 'password' => $this->password, 'role' => 'admin'])) {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('error', ['message' => 'Invalid Credentials, Check your credentials']);
            return;
        }
        $user = User::whereEmail($this->email)->first();
        $auth_user = Auth::login($user, $this->remember);

        dd(auth()->user()) <- this returns authenticated user;

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('success', ['message' => 'Login Successfully']);

        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
```

Then in my custom auth middleware

```
 dd(auth()->user()); <- this returns null
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        }

        if (auth()->user()->role != 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        }

        return $next($request);
```

I know it has to do with the spa stateful auth setup i did. Is there a way to make both work?

Answer (score 1):

You could send the created token to the dashboard app and resend it in each API request from the dashboard

- first: you need to create user token and send it in the login response see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens)
- second: in your dashboard app store token and resend it in each API request